# Criterions for 3x3 PD matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

What are some sufficient conditions for a 3 by 3 Matrix to be positive (semi) definite?

I ask because I need to know the convexity of $f(x,y,z)=-x^2-y^2-z^2+0.5xy$.  I can compute the Hessian of $f$, but I need to know if it the Hessian is SPD or not inorder to deduce convexity.

Comment: What you have is a quadratic form. Write it in matrix form as $u^T P u$ where $u=(x,y,z)^T$. Then calculate the eigenvalues of $P$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General Answer:

$X\in \Re^{n\times n}$ is PSD if $u^TXu\geq0$ for all $u\in \Re^n$.

For Symmetric Matrices:

(You can prove this, it is quite simply)

$X\in \Re^{n\times n}$ is PSD if all of its eigenvalues are positive.

---

So, in your case:
$$\nabla^2f(x)=\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 0.5& 0\\
 0.5& -2&0 \\
 0& 0& -2\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

The Hessian has eigenvalues $(-2.5,-2,-1.5)$.  Which makes it not-convex. (In fact, this function is concave).

Comment: Yeah, beauty, thanks.